# Django: join two table on foreign key to third table?

Tags: python, django

I have three models

```py
class A(Model):
    ...

class B(Model):
    id = IntegerField()
    a = ForeignKey(A)

class C(Model):
    id = IntegerField()
    a = ForeignKey(A)
```

I want get the pairs of (B.id, C.id), for which B.a==C.a. How do I make that join using the django orm?

Comment: There are potentially *many* instances of B and C for each A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django allows you to [reverse the lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) in much the same way that you can use do a forward lookup using `__`:

> It works backwards, too. To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just use the lowercase name of the model.
>
> This example retrieves all **`Blog`** objects which have at least one Entry whose headline contains 'Lennon':
>
> `Blog.objects.filter(entry__headline__contains='Lennon')`

I think you can do something like this, with @Daniel Roseman's caveat about the type of result set that you will get back.

```
ids = B.objects.prefetch_related('a', 'a__c').values_list('id', 'a__c__id')
```

The prefetch related will help with performance in older versions of django if memory serves.