# Django: select multiple columns across different apps with the same foreign key

Tags: django

This is a follow-up question of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58915820/5223223).

I have `app1/models.py`:

```py
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class B(models.Model):
    fid = models.ForeignKey(A, models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class C(models.Model):
    fid = models.ForeignKey(A, models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

and `app2/models.py`:

```py
from app1.models import A

class D(models.Model):
    fid = models.ForeignKey(A, models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

I wish to get `A.text` `B.text` `C.text` `D.text` where `A.id == B.fid == C.fid == D.fid == 1`. From the referred question, I was able to retrieve the first 3 columns using:

```py
B.objects.filter(fid=1).values('text', 'fid__text', 'fid__c__text') # B.text, A.text, C.text
```

However I cannot get `D.text` using this query. I know I can do a filter on `D` and give it a manual calculation, but I'm looking forward to a more Djangoic way.

(In case of a multi-match, product the rows, so if there are 2 rows in `B` that matches the given `fid` and 3, 4 for `C`, `D`, a total of 24 rows in returned.)

---

**For future visitors**: both weAreStarsDust's and nigel222's answer are great and worth reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try query from `A` model

```
A.objects.filter(id=1).values('text', 'b__text', 'c__text', 'd__text')
```

or

```
A.objects.filter(id=1).values('text', 'b_set__text', 'c_set__text', 'd_set__text')
```

More details about `_set` can be found in the [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager) docs

Comment: Raises `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'd' into field. Choices are: b, c, id, text`. Should I import D in `app1.models`?

Comment: No, import is not the case. Does your D model been migrated?

Comment: Yes, and both `app1` and `app2` exist in `settings.py`.

Comment: And if you print `dir(A.objects.first())` is there some names that related to D model?

Comment: I found `d_set`, but I have no `set` field in `D`.

Comment: Try `A.objects.filter(id=1).values('text', 'b__text', 'c__text', 'd_set__text')`. You can read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager) about _set in RelatedManager

Comment: @dibery consider accepting the answer, if it was useful.

Comment: Yes, I will. Just need some time to test all answers. Thanks for reminding.

Comment: After some tests, I found `d__text` to work. (No migration applied during these times.) I kindly ask you if you can add both versions in your answer so that it may help more future readers.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it doesn't work. Is it a database error? In which case it may be nothing to do with Django. Does it work if you replace `fid__c__text` with `fid__d__text`?

I would instinctively query on the `A` model instance, which is the 'parent' of the others. Having obtained the instance `a`, it offers `b_set.all()`, `c_set.all()`, and `d_set.all()`. For DB efficiency you can prefetch all the related objects with

```
a = A.objects.prefetch_related('b', 'c', 'd').get( pk=b.fid_id )
```

(Note, having prefetched, filter by iterating through `a.b_set.all()` not by applying a `.filter(criteria)` which will hit the DB again regardless of the prefetch).

Comment: `fid__d__text` doesn't work. `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'd' into field. Choices are: b, c, id, text`

Comment: For prefetch: `AttributeError: Cannot find 'b' on A object, 'b' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`

Comment: re prefetch: my error. the default related_name is `b_set`. (I always code an explicit related_name).

Comment: re: `fid__d__text` I think this shows it's not creating an inverse relation across apps. (I didn't know this). Try explicitly coding (on D) `related_name="d"` to force `a.d` to exist.

Comment: I think weAreStarsDust's answer and comments are likely more correct than my answer.

Comment: Both your answers are excellent and help me a lot. (Yes, your modified answer also works.) Though not accepted, I'll give you an upvote. It'd be an even better answer if you can add where to put `related_name` in `D`.

Comment: That's `class D(models.Model):` related name (on A)  `fid = models.ForeignKey(A, models.CASCADE, related_name='d')`